# Visual Studio & TFS: How to add a custom tab on Check In

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, tfs, add-in

I want to write a custom Plugin for the "Check In" window in VS.
It should be a new point in in the menu and replace the view on the right. To make it more clear I've attached an image.

I don't want do write a new policy and the Check-in notes are not customizable enough for me, I've already looked into that.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks!
Simon

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's really not possible at all.

> No, this dialog is not currently
>   extensible in VS.  We have received
>   this request before, and it's on our
>   backlog for consideration in a future
>   release of VS.
>   Quote by a Microsoft employee.
>   See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/5772f93b-d234-43c0-83c1-f5dfa0c316bf

Comment: Well, there's impossible, and there's "impossible". Since it is software, I'm pretty sure it is possible, but it might be "impossible", aka extremely hard and a lot of work.